# Swift - How an IBACTION performs segue

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, segue

I can pass data (authorID) to a view using `DidSelectRowAtIndexPath` successfully.
Now I try to perform the same segue with an Button IBACTION, But I couldn't find a way to perform it. I couldn't find a way to use NSIndexPath inside INACTION.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       performSegueWithIdentifier("ArticleSegue", sender: indexPath) 
       tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
 }

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ArticleSegue"{
            let toView = segue.destinationViewController as! ArticleTableViewController
            let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath
            let authorid = articleList?[indexPath.row]["author_id"].int!
            toView.authorid = authorid            
}

@IBAction func favButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
 //???
}
```

Comment: So every row in your tableView has got a favButton? Do you use custom cells?

Comment: yes, I have a custom cell and every row has a favButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could solve it, as you just need the row of the cell (here indexPath.row for your articleList), is to give your favButtons a tag (if you don't use the UIView-tags for something else).

This means when you configure your cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you just say:

```
cell.favButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

then in your IBAction, create an NSIndexPath with that tag and call the segue:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ManualSegue", sender: indexPath)
```

Make sure the sender in this case is an UIView (here UIButton).

Comment: How I am going to call it in prepareForSegue? I got error for  "let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath" inside the if check. Error is "Could not cast value of type 'UIButton' (0x111798f68) to 'NSIndexPath' (0x10f670680)"

Comment: then you probably configured a segue by the favButton in your Storyboard. Check if the favButton is highlighted if you click on the segue in the storyboard. If so, delete the segue and create a new, manual segue by clicking on the "sending" viewcontroller and control-dragging to the target viewcontroller of your segue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined the segue as a manual segue between two view controllers, you can just call

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("ManualSegue", sender: self)
```

Another possibility is that you define the segue from the button itself to the target view controller. In that case, it happens automatically; you need neither an `IBAction` nor a call to `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

Answer (score 0):

there's a method for it

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("ArticleSegue", sender:self)
```

Comment: I can't do this because every row has a uniq id I need to pass with the segue

Answer (score 0):

Assign the `Row` to the tag of the `UIButton` in your

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Setup cell etc..
    ....
    cell.favButton.tag = indexPath.row
    ...
    return cell
}
```

Then in your action method, note the change in the method from `AnyObject` to `UIButton!` so you can access the tag property.

```
@IBAction func favButtonDidTouch(sender: UIButton!) {
  performSegueWithIdentifier("ArticleSegue", sender:NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0))
}
```

Comment: How do I need to call  "indexPath" inside prepareForSegue ?

Comment: You call it the same as previously, as you are passing in an `NSIndexPath` object the same as you are in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in the error you posted, it appears you are passing a `UIButton` which is incorrect.